# Unwanted Dictionary Update When Adding Multiple Dictionaries to a List

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append, updates

In Python, I'm trying to create a list consisting of 2 independent dictionaries (`dict1` & `dict2`). However, when I add them both to a new list using append and update methods, it seems to change my `dict1` dictionary.

```
n = []
dict1 = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
dict2 = {"c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5}

n.append(dict1)
n[0].update(dict2)
```

This gives me result I want for `n` but it also overwrites my `dict1`, which is not desired.

```
dict1 
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
```

Why is this happening? How can I achieve my goal of joining the 2 dicts into a list without modifying my first dict? This code serves the purpose of joining 2 JSON docs into one, in case anyone is wondering.

Comment: that's because `dict1` and `n[0]` are referring *to the same dict*. If you want a copy, use a copy: `n.append(dict1.copy())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you are referencing the same dict when you do the `.update()`.  So you can use `.copy()` to do an explicit copy and get an initial dict that can then be updated.

```
n.append(dict1.copy())
n[0].update(dict2)
```

Or if you have two dicts, you can do it in one line like:

```
n.append(dict(dict1, **dict2))
```

Or you can explicitly start with an empty dict, and then update like::

```
n.append({})
n[0].update(dict1)
n[0].update(dict2)
```