# Python for loop and dictionary index not working as expected

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I made a program that takes a list of users in a conversation and a list of the messages in that conversation, containing each message a **username** and **time** attribute.

What I intended to do is check when there is a response (when the 
`msgList[i].usnername != msgList[i-1].username`), check who makes this response and how many minutes it took, and then sum 1 to a dictionary counting the responses that took `dif` minutes

```
def getResponseTime(userList, msgList):
    thresholds = [5, 15, 30, 60, 120, "inf"]
    k = dict.fromkeys(thresholds, 0)
    avl = dict.fromkeys(userList, k)

    for i in range(len(msgList)):
        if msgList[i].username != msgList[i-1].username:
            # response
            dif = (msgList[i].time - msgList[i-1].time).total_seconds()/60
            if dif > 0 and dif <= 5:
                avl[msgList[i].username][5] += 1
            elif dif > 5 and dif <= 15:
                avl[msgList[i].username][15] += 1
            elif dif > 15 and dif <= 30:
                avl[msgList[i].username][30] += 1
            elif dif > 30 and dif <= 60:
                avl[msgList[i].username][60] += 1
            elif dif > 60 and dif <= 120:
                avl[msgList[i].username][120] += 1
            else:
                avl[msgList[i].username]["inf"] += 1

    return avl
```

And I get this output:

```
{'Lau': {5: 8223, 15: 1758, 30: 493, 60: 318, 120: 181, 'inf': 10081}, 'Fco': {5: 8223, 15: 1758, 30: 493, 60: 318, 120: 181, 'inf': 10081}}
```

As you can see the results are the same for both users, and I can not find any bug in the code that might explain this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unwanted Dictionary Update When Adding Multiple Dictionaries to a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492574/unwanted-dictionary-update-when-adding-multiple-dictionaries-to-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=fromkeys#dict.fromkeys, the second argument of `fromkeys` is a single value that all of the keys point to, so each of your keys points to the same dictionary in memory. When you increment some value for what appears to be one user, it actually increments it for all users!

Instead, you should use a nested `defaultdict` from the `collections` module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Here's the modification:

```
import collections

def getResponseTime(userList, msgList):
    thresholds = [5, 15, 30, 60, 120, "inf"]
    avl = collections.defaultdict(lambda : collections.defaultdict(int))

    for i in range(len(msgList)):
        if msgList[i].username != msgList[i-1].username:
            # response
            dif = (msgList[i].time - msgList[i-1].time).total_seconds()/60
            if dif > 0 and dif <= 5:
                avl[msgList[i].username][5] += 1
            elif dif > 5 and dif <= 15:
                avl[msgList[i].username][15] += 1
            elif dif > 15 and dif <= 30:
                avl[msgList[i].username][30] += 1
            elif dif > 30 and dif <= 60:
                avl[msgList[i].username][60] += 1
            elif dif > 60 and dif <= 120:
                avl[msgList[i].username][120] += 1
            else:
                avl[msgList[i].username]["inf"] += 1

    return avl
```

`avl` is now a dictionary where, when you access a key that doesn't exist yet, it makes that key point to *another* defaultdict to hold the threshold numbers, which has the same behavior except that it defaults to `0` when you try to get a key that doesn't exist.